# I want to leave always one record if table record count = 1 with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I can delete records with this SQL clause,

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 2
```

I need to always leave one record if table count = 1 even if "ID=2". How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?  Do you want to delete all the rows in the table except one?  Or do you only want to delete the row where `ID = 2` *unless* it's the only row left in the table?

Comment: Yes as you said i can delete all rows in the table except one. But excepted one can be not static value. 

Andomar's suggest works well. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a WHERE clause to ensure there's more than one row:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID = 2
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something in the lines of this might work?

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 2 LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID=2);
```

Maybe add in an if-statement to ensure count is above 1.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow variable limit clauses, see: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6673

Comment: Oh, well then your solution is superior.

Comment: i could not apply your suggest to my project. sure it can work, absolutely i could not.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to disallow any delete that empties the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_D FOR DELETE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
GO
```

More complex, what if you do this multirow delete that empties the table?

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

so, randomly repopulate from what you just deleted

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_D FOR DELETE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable)
    INSERT mytable (col2, col2, ..., coln)
    SELECT TOP 1 col2, col2, ..., coln FROM INSERTED --ORDER BY ??

GO
```

However, the requirement is a bit dangerous and vague. In English, OK, "always have at least one row in the table", but in practice "which row?"

Comment: Thank you too. But your suggest level is hard for my SQL knowledge level :) May be i can use your suggest in future.